# prevent flutter plugin screenshot

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I have used and tried Flutter window manager and Also added secure flags in the Main activity. It prevents the screenshot in the rest of the app, but when I open Epub files using [epub_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/epub_viewer), Inside the epub viewer, screenshots are working. How can I prevent this?